# How MATLAB divide the number of iterations of "parfor" on the workers of one computer?

Tags: parallel-processing

Please, I have a question, how MATLAB divide the number of iterations of "parfor" on the workers of the computer?

In the following example of Mathworks in the picture, as I understood, they mentioned when the number of iteration is 10 and the number of workers is 4, the first three workers take the 2 iterations equally then the remaining four iterations divide into the four. That is mean the first three workers take 3 iterations and the last worker take just one iteration.

Please, could anyone correct me if I am wrong ! And please, explain to me how MATLAB divide the number of iterations, i.e. even or odd ?

Lease, if I have this case how MATLAB divide the iterations ?
1. If the number of iteration is 40 and we have 4 workers.
2. If the number of iteration is 40 and we have 5 workers.
3. If the number of iteration is 40 and we have 8 workers.
4. If the number of iteration is 40 and we have 12 workers.

Kind regards
Ammar
[image: parfor]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would like to know the answer as well. Because we do not know what exactly the idea of division the number of iterations on the number of workers.

Kind regards
Fahdi